# list iteration using index of the list element

Tags: python

I want to access list items in a specific way. for an example

```
l1 =[1,2,3,4,5]
```

now i want to access 3rd element in the list i.e 4 but i want the result in specific way.

I want program to get the 2nd element i.e 3 and using its index i want to find 3rd element.

in short

```
print l1[index]

index2 = index+1

print l1[index2]
```

how can i accomplish this task? is there any other efficient way to do this task?

thank you

Comment: What's the end goal? You can do `i = l1.index(4)` and then `l1[i+1]` but this only gives you back index for the first match (`['a', 'b', 'a'].index('a')`
is `0`). What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to print i th element and using that its index i want to print i+1 th element

Comment: What if `i`th element is the last one?

Comment: This question is confusing to me. I would think that you'd want `print l1[l1[index]]` but I don't think that that's what you want?

Comment: thats the other thing but i asked this question to perform some other task where i dont have to worry about this condition

Comment: I don't get it, what is wrong with the code example you have? if you want to show the element in index 3 then do `index=3`, and `index2` will be the element after... What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for i, elem in enumerate(l1):
...     print 'Current', elem
...     try:
...         print 'Next', l1[i+1]
...     except IndexError:
...         print '%d is the last item in the list' % elem
...
```

This outputs

```
Current 1
Next 2
Current 2
Next 3
Current 3
Next 4
Current 4
Next 5
Current 5
Next 5 is the last item in the list
>>>
```

You could also start enumerating at index 1 and not add to index when looking up the next item:

```
>>> for i, elem in enumerate(l1, start=1):
...     print 'Current', elem
...     try:
...         print 'Next', l1[i]
...     except IndexError:
...         print '%d is the last item in the list' % elem
...         
Current 1
Next 2
Current 2
Next 3
Current 3
Next 4
Current 4
Next 5
Current 5
Next 5 is the last item in the list
>>>
```

Comment: well let me try this one

Answer (score 1):

> I want program to get the 2nd element i.e 3 and using its index i want to find 3rd element.

```
i = 1         # Get the 2nd element
print l1[i+1] # Using its index find the 3rd element.
```

Comment: Maybe OP will, in explaining why this is wrong, shed more light on his requirement.